# Building ExpoKit for Distribution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, expo

I have an ExpoKit app running and ready to be distributed. While I'm confident with the building process for normal Expo apps I have never built ExpoKit apps and would like a step-by-step guide for iOS (and Android, if possible) as I haven't found it on any of the official Expo resources.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean for more docs? You open the projects in either Xcode or intellij , then build as normal for those respective platforms.